# C# fill DataGridView by return from other class

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview, return, fill

Hi I have a program to parse a CSV and fill it into a DataGridView.

When I'm doing it like this it works great:

```
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files(*.csv)|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtCsvSource.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(txtCsvSource.Text, iso), true))
            {
               csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
               dataGridView1.DataSource = csv;
            }
        }
```

But when Im doing it like this:

```
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files(*.csv)|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtCsvSource.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = QrFunctions.parsecsv(txtCsvSource.Text);
            dataGridView1.Update();
        }
```

with the QrFunctions.parsecsv being like:

```
public CachedCsvReader parsecsv(string csvpath)
    {
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(csvpath, iso), true))
        {
            csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
            return csv;
        }
    }
```

the DataGridView is empty... why? I simply have no idea :-( I just wanted to use this function to parse in another Class, so I created the class QrFunctions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
public CachedCsvReader parsecsv(string csvpath)
    {   
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(csvpath, iso), true)
        {
            csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
            return csv;
        }
    }
```

Please remember to dispose of the object yourself, since I have removed the using statement or implement the [IDisposable pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Thanks to @MartiniMoe for constructive comments.

Comment: This doesnt change anything :-(
I wonder why it should work, are you just copying the CachedCsvReader and returning the second one?

Comment: @MartiniMoe - this answer looked correct to me too since the using disposes of you csv reader when you leave your function. Could you let us know where the CachedCsvReader class comes from so we can duplicate the code?

Comment: @MartiniMoe In your first, code sample, you didnt have to use dataGridView1.Update(); when you bind the dataGridView1 to CachedCsvReader, why did you use it in your second code sample? Also use a debugger to check, if your getting any data back when you set the datasource property in your second code sample.

Comment: I used it just to try. I managed to get everything working with following code:
`public static CachedCsvReader parsecsv(string csvpath)
        {
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(csvpath, iso), true);
            csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;
            return csv;
        }`
Dont really know why it works this way... but it does :)

Comment: @MartiniMoe - actually that makes perfect sense - the using causes the StreamReader to be disposed, so even when you then assign to a csv reader outside the using, it still won't work. One thing to note is that you will need to call .Dispose() yourself now or implement IDisposable yourself to be safe. Also - post your comment as an answer, since it is different from the posted answer (or alykhalid you could edit your answer)

Answer (score 0):

Alykhalid's answer was almost correct except it looks like the `Dispose` method of the `CachedCsvReader` is calling `Dispose` on the `StreamReader`.

All a using statement is, is syntactic sugar for the following code:

```
try
{
    var yourObject = new SomeIDisposable();
    // Some code using yourObject
}
finally
{
    yourObject.Dispose();
}
```

So the using around `CachedCsvReader` is calling the Dispose() method of the reader, which I'm guessing looks something like:

```
void Dispose()
{
    streamReader.Dispose();
}
```

So once you are outside the using block, dispose has been called on the `StreamReader` and even when you copy your csv reader reference to an object outside the using, your stream itself has been closed so your `DataGridView` receives no data.

As you have found, this can be fixed by removing the using statement, but this has the downside that you are now **not closing** your stream, which can have some undesired effects.

To follow safest practices you should either:

- Make QrFunctions implement IDisposable so you can use a using statement (which really just puts you back where you started)
- Call .Dispose() on the CachedCsvReader you return.
- Put the using statement back in your helper function but read the stream inside the using - hopefully the CSV reader can be forced to read straight away and return some sort of List of csv rows. Then you just return the list rather than the CSV reader. Your code would look something like:

  ```
  public List<CSVRows> parsecsv(string csvpath)
  {
      Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");                       
      using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(csvpath, iso), true))                       
      {                       
          csv.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty;                       
          // I have no idea what this method is but if it exists it could be called ToList or Read    
          return csv.ToList<CSVRows>();                       
      } 
  }
  ```